# No such column: ID(code1): , while compling: SELECT *

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have homework but it has some errors, here is my code:

```
private void initUI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i =getIntent();
    String id =i.getStringExtra("ID");
    SQLiteDatabase database = Database.initDatabase(this, DB_NAME);
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID = "+id,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String ten = cursor.getString(1);
    String sdt = cursor.getString(2);
    String classid = cursor.getString(3);
    byte[] anh= cursor.getBlob(4);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(anh, 0,anh.length);
    imgupdate.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    edtid.setText(id);
    edtname.setText(ten);
    edtsdt.setText(sdt);
}
```

and error

> 12-07 22:55:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(15694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-07 22:55:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(15694): Process:
>   com.example.assignment_android_ps04360, PID: 15694 12-07 22:55:13.831:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15694): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.assignment_android_ps04360/com.example.assignment_android_ps04360.UpdateActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ID (code 1):
>   , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID = PS04107 12-07
>   22:55:13.831: E/AndroidRuntime(15694):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)

**The table:**
[Table.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nynkv.png)

Comment: Have you defined the Student table correctly?

Comment: Can you show the table of Student?

Comment: It simply states the error that `ID` column is not present inside the Student table!

Comment: i have attached the table, it's table.png

Comment: Attach the table DDL not a photo

Comment: Does the phrase “SQL injection attack” mean anything to you?  What if someone enters an ID of `'PS04107'; DELETE FROM Student; --`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to debug this is to run the query directly against sqlite before putting it in a program.

One problem here is that the value you're comparing to `ID` is not a quoted string. You need to produce something more like

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID = 'PS04107'
```

Rather than building the query as a string you should [pass `selectionArgs` to the `query` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).